# Surface Keyboard Shortcuts in Tablet Mode?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-surface, on-screen-keyboard

From what I've seen of the Surface Book 2's On-Screen Keyboard in Tablet Mode, many Keyboard Shortcuts wouldn't be possible (e.g. CTRL + Shift + Tab). Are there any good work-arounds to this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the onscreen keyboard to its full layout,

- Go to **Start > Settings > Devices.**
- Click on **Typing.**
- Toggle on **Add the standard keyboard layout as a touch keyboard option.**
- Turn on the Onscreen keyboard from the taskbar.
- Click on the button shown: (bottom right)
  [image: onscreen]
- Click on the standard keyboard option(rightmost button).

Now you should have all the keys required to execute shortcuts on your tablet PC.